# Чем отличается "атрибут" и "поле" в терминологии SQL?

Tags: sql, база-данных, терминология

Чем отличается атрибут и поле в SQL?

Поле - это вся строка (запись) или нет?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Термина [*поле* (*field*)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65614) в стандарте SQL нет, есть - *колонка* или *столбец* (*column*).

Тем не менее, термин *поле* иногда встречается потому, что некоторые производители (которые слеши переворачивают и лишние знаки в конeц строки добавляют) и здесь не удержались внести что-то своё. Например, в [мануале к *MS Access*](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-table-and-add-fields-8fdc65f9-8d40-4ff5-9212-80e6545e8d87?ocmsassetID=HA010072883&CorrelationId=5c0567d7-fb5c-433b-ad63-a5b3e1cd2583&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) совершенно очевидно, то, что называется *полем* эквивалентно *колонке*.

Хотя между терминами *атрибут* и *колонка* есть связь, но это не одно и тоже.

В *логической* модели данных (*ERM=Entity Relationship Model*) у *объектa* (*entity*) есть *атрибуты* (*attributes*) его описывающие. Например, для объекта "вещица" есть три атрибута:

> [[**item**] name, type, description]

На основе *логической* модели данных создаётся *физическая модель* данных:

```
create table items (
    name varchar (16) not null, 
    type char (8) not null,  
    description varchar (256),
    constraint itempk primary key (name, type))
```

И тут правильно будет сказать: для "вещиц" создана *таблица*, которая содержит три *колонки*.

Answer (score 5):

Атрибут сущности - это именованная характеристика, являющаяся некоторым свойством сущности.
Таким образом атрибут и поле это одно и то же.
Строка и запись тоже синонимы.
А вот поле и запись как вы понимаете уже нет.